# Are these two functions identical with respect to this $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

> **Definition1**
>
> Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space and $(X,\mathfrak{M})$ be a measurable space and $G:\Omega\times \mathfrak{M}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a function.
>
> We say $G$ is a **Markov kernel** from $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ to $(X,\mathfrak{M})$ if $G(\cdot,A):(\Omega,\mathscr{F})\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is measurable and $G(x,\cdot):\mathfrak{M}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is a probability measure.
>
> **Definition2**
>
> Let $G$ be a markov kernel under the same setting in the Definition1, and let $\{A_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}$ be a finite sequence in $\mathfrak{M}$.
>
> Define $V(x):=(G(x,A_1),...,G(x,A_n))$. We say $V_*P$ (the pushforward measure of $V$, that is, $V_*P(B)=P(V^{-1}(B))$ for all $B$) is a finite distribution of $G$ with respect to $\{A_i\}$

Let $(X,\mathfrak{M})$ be a measurable space and $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space.

Let $G,H$ be Markov kernels from $(\Omega, \mathscr{F},P)$ to $(X,\mathfrak{M})$ such that all the finite distributions are equal.

Note that there are two scenarios.

**[[First case]]**

Note that we can view $G,H$ as *measurable functions* from $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$ to $(\prod_{A\in\mathfrak{M}} [0,\infty],\otimes_{A\in \mathfrak{M}} \mathscr{B}_{[0,\infty]})$ ($\mathscr{B}_{[0,\infty]}$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,\infty]$). Since finite distributions are equal, by **Kolmogorov extension theorem**, we have $G_*P=H_*P$. That is, these measures are equal on the $\sigma$-algebra $\otimes_{A\in \mathfrak{M}} \mathscr{B}_{[0,\infty]}$.

**[[Second Case]]**

Note that we can also view $G,H$ as functions from $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$ to $Prob(X,\mathfrak{M})$ ($Prob(X,\mathfrak{M})$ denotes the collection of probability measures on the space $(X,\mathfrak{M})$).

To make $G,H$ *measurable*, we now equip a suitable $\sigma$-algebra on $Prob(X,\mathfrak{M})$ as follows:

Define $\pi_A:Prob(X,\mathfrak{M})\rightarrow [0,\infty]:\lambda\mapsto \lambda(A)$ for each $A\in\mathfrak{M}$. Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which makes all $\pi_A$'s measurable. That is, $\mathscr{C}=\sigma(\bigcup_A \pi_A)$.

Since $G,H$ are *Markov kernels*, we can now see that $G,H:(\Omega,\mathscr{F})\rightarrow (Prob(X,\mathfrak{M}),\mathscr{C})$ are measurable!

My questions is the following:

Are $G_*P=H_*P$ on $\mathscr{C}$?

The condition "equal in finite distributions" implies the equality of the pushforward measures in the *first case*, but I am curious if this condition also implies the equality of the pushforward measure in the *second case*.